# How to describe an expected play-json Reads format programmatically

Tags: json, scala, reflection, playframework, play-json

I have many case classes that defines json `Read`/`Write`/`Format` using play-json library.
Typical example of such a definition is done using macro

```
case class Payload(
                    file: FilePayLoad,
                    comment: String
                  )

object Payload {
  implicit val format: Format[Payload] = Json.format[Payload]
}
```

No trouble for writing more specific formats or anything else using the library apis.

Is there any possibility to perform reflection or type analysis on the `OReads` implicit defined ? 
I now little about type level programming, and enough about implicits to retrieve the implicits generated by the macro expansion but I'm working on a self discoverable REST api and I would need to print out the expected JSON format for a given payload case class

Is there any way to reverse the play-json reads definition to print something like this

```
 "format": {
    "/payload": {
        "/file": {
            "type": "FilePayLoad"
            "format": {
                "/name": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "optional": false
                },
                "/mimeType": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "optional": false
                },
                "/filesize": {
                    "type": "Double",
                    "optional": false
                },
            },
        },
        "/comment": {
            "type": String,
            "optional": false
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: There is `OReads` and the `Reads` is not designed to be discoverable/autodocumented. Rather generate the `Reads` from documented types/AST descriptors, and expose the that as REST documentation (not so trivial ...)

Comment: The ```play-swagger``` library does something similar to your goal to auto generate your api documentation using reflection. it does a good job on most cases. I suggest you start reading that library's code to reverse engineer the process or just use the library itself altogether if you wish